# Spring Webflux - "scanAvailable": true

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I'm using a `RouterFunction` to define endpoints in my Spring Boot application. My service returns a `Mono<Object>` and I want to return the result of this when the endpoint is called. I also need to authenticate so I pass a `UserPrinciple` object through.

**Router**

```
@Bean
RouterFunction<ServerResponse> router() {
    return route()
            .GET("/api/endpoint-name", this::getExample)
            .build();
}

private Mono<ServerResponse> getExample(ServerRequest request) {
    return ServerResponse.ok().body(fromPublisher(getUserPrincipal().map(service::getSomething), Object.class)).log();
}

private Mono<UserPrincipal> getUserPrincipal() {
    return ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext()
            .map(ctx -> ctx.getAuthentication())
            .map(auth -> auth.getPrincipal())
            .map(UserPrincipal.class::cast);
}
```

**Service**

```
public Mono<Object> getSomething(UserPrincipal userPrincipal) {
    WebClient webClient = getWebClient(userPrincipal.getJwt());

    return webClient.get()
            .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.path("another/server/endpoint").build())
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(Object.class);
}
```

The endpoint is returning this:

```
{
    "scanAvailable": true
}
```

which suggests that I'm passing the `Mono` into the body of the response instead of passing in the result. However I've used `fromPublisher` which I thought would resolve this.

I can't find any examples where the service returns a `Mono` and the route correctly returns the result of the `Mono`.

How can I correctly pass a `Mono/Flux` as the body of the response?

Comment: try removing the `fromPublisher`

Comment: @Toerktumlare Same `scanAvailable` response with and without.

Comment: then dont return a `Mono<Object>` and actually use the type system and avoid `Object`, and try that. Im Not really sure how `.map(service::getSomething)`compiles, since `map` does not return `Mono`. But i have no compiler here to check your code.

Comment: Shouldn't it work with an Object? This works successfully `return ServerResponse.ok().body(Mono.just("example response"), Object.class).log();`

Comment: i think it has to do with you returning a `Mono` from a `map` function which should not work, as `map`is sychronous, and returns concrete values, while `flatMap` is `async` which means it returns `producers`

Comment: That was it! I didn't realise the difference. Removing `fromPublisher` and changing `map` to `flatMap` fixed it. Feel free to answer the question and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

im not going to explain the difference between `map`and `flatMap`since i have already written a quite comprehensive explanation here:

[Do you have a test to show differences between the reactor map() and flatMap()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65689935/do-you-have-a-test-to-show-differences-between-the-reactor-map-and-flatmap/65692723#65692723)

The problem in the above code is the return of `Object`. And input parameters of `Object` into certain functions. The first function is pretty straight forward

```
Mono<UserPrincipal> = getUserPrincipal();
```

While the second one gets a bit more hairy:

```
Mono<Mono<Object> value = getUserPrincipal().map(service::getSomething);
```

So why are we getting A nested Mono?, well the get something returns a `Mono<Object>` and the `Map` return according the the api is `Mono<R>` where `R` is what we return from `getSomething`.

We then stick it into the `fromPublisher` which will unrap the first `Mono` ending up trying to serialize the `Mono<Object>`resulting in the strange response.

```
{
    "scanAvailable": true
}
```

The answer here is pay more close attention to the type system. The `body` function takes a `Publisher` (Mono or Flux) so you don't need the `fromPublisher` function.

And also changing `map` to `flatMap` since the return type from inside a `flatMap` is a `publisher`.

```
ServerResponse.ok()
    .body(getUserPrincipal()
    .flatMap(service::getSomething), Object.class));
```