# what is a MonoNext in Webflux and how to choose which one to use between flatMap and map

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, project-reactor

The following code was about to first delete a KV from redis, and then set a new KV there and return. But it actually never `set` after `delete`. I only see mistake after print every `log`, as `2 any is MonoNext`. Then I released a chain step before this `any` needs to split off one `Mono`, so I used `flatMap` instead of `map` at marker. This problem is more likely happened to me, especially when functions are deeply encapsulated inside another function with `Mono` in and out.

```
    @RequestMapping("addUserSimple3")
    public Mono<AddUserResponse> addUser3(@RequestBody Mono<AddUserVo> vo) {
        return vo.flatMap(v ->
                redisOps.delete(v.getGroupId())
                        .map(any -> {   <---------------------Use flatMap instead of map
                            log.info("1 any is {}", any);
                            return redisOps.set(v.getGroupId(), v.getPersonId());
                        })
                        .map(any ->
                        {
                            log.info("2 any is {}", any);
                            return new AddUserResponse(ResponseState.GOOD, v.getLogId());
                        })
        );
    }
```

Then my question is, how to better understand `MonoNext` and `flatMap`? (aka, I let the above code work by replacing `map` but I don't understand why it did not work, and why it does later)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do you have a test to show differences between the reactor map() and flatMap()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65689935/do-you-have-a-test-to-show-differences-between-the-reactor-map-and-flatmap)

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR** In case operation is asynchronous (returns `Mono` or `Flux`) - use `flatMap`, for synchronous logic use `map`.

In reactive nothing happens until you subscribe. `flatMap` subscribes to the  provided publisher, returning the value emitted by another `Mono` or `Flux`. `map` just transforms the value applying a synchronous function to it.

```
@RequestMapping("addUserSimple3")
public Mono<AddUserResponse> addUser3(@RequestBody Mono<AddUserVo> vo) {
    return vo.flatMap(v ->
            redisOps.delete(v.getGroupId())
                    .flatMap(res -> redisOps.set(v.getGroupId(), v.getPersonId()))
                    .map(res -> new AddUserResponse(ResponseState.GOOD, v.getLogId()))
    );
}
```