# Webflux : Difference between .map() and .flatMap() behavior in a kafka receiver

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I have gone through the `project reactor` documentation for `map()` and `flatMap()` method and also a good explanation in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65692723/6366458) answer.

But my query is regarding when we use the `reactor` `KafkaReceiver`. Following code example I have :

```
    //start of consumption    
    public Disposable consumeMessage() {
        return processKafkaRecord().subscribe(record -> log.info("success"),
                error -> log.error("error logged" + error));
    }

    public Flux<String> processKafkaRecord() {
         Flux<ReceiverRecord<String, String>> receiverRecord = Flux.defer(() -> inputEventReceiver.receive());
         return receiverRecord.doOnNext(record -> log.info("Input Event receiver record {}", record.toString()))
            .flatMap(this::processMessage)
            .doOnComplete(() -> log.info("MSG=Completed consuming messages from topic={}" +"for Cancel Validation processing.", inputEventKafkaConfig.getTopic()));
    }

    private Flux<String> processMessage(final ReceiverRecord<String, String> receiverRecord) {
         //logic
        .flatMap(this::processOne);
        .flatMap(this::processTwo);
        .flatMap(this::processThree);
    }
```

My doubt in short is if I use `.map()` method in `processMessage` instead of `.flatMap()` function will it have any difference in performance for the `KafkaReceiver`?

Doubt explained : When consuming a stream of data in `KafkaReceiver` we already using a `flux` for consumption and in `processKafkaRecord` method the call happens through a `flatMap()` method, so each individual record should be processed in async with this only.

And once we reach `processMessage()` method, it is actually processing a single record. Now if my `processOne`, `processTwo` and `processThree` method has to happen in synchronous manner for each individual event, does it make sense to use `flatMap()` instead of `map()`.

Once a flatMap() method was called in processKafkaRecord() method, the inner method will already be in async for each event. And using map would make more sense if each process in the processMessage has to happen in synchronous manner?
Or I am wrong with this conclusion, and we should use flatMap even in inner method for performance?

Answer (score 1):

It really depends what is your processing logic but it looks like you are mixing concurrency, parallelism and asynchronous/non-blocking execution. Asynchronous execution doesn't mean fire and forget. It's more about no-blocking execution. Logic could still be sequential.

### `map` vs `flatMap`

- use `flatMap` to execute async/reactive logic such as http requests, db read/write, other I/O bound operations and returns `Mono` or `Flux`.
- use `map` to execute sync logic such as object mapping.

### Concurrency

By default, `flatMap` will process `Queues.SMALL_BUFFER_SIZE = 256` number of in-flight inner sequences concurrently.

You could control concurrency `flatMap(item -> process(item), concurrency)` or use `concatMap` operator if you want to process sequentially. Check [flatMap(..., int concurrency, int prefetch)](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-int-int-) for details.

There are different "flavors" of `flatMap`. If you need sequential processing - use `concatMap` that is basically `flatMap` with concurrency = 1.

### Kafka ordered vs unordered processing

Depending on use case there are several options.

**Ordered message processing**
In case message order is important and messages should be processed in the same sequence as they are sent by producer. Kafka guarantees message order per partition.

In Reactior Kafka you can do it by grouping data per partition and then process then sequentially

```
kafkaReceiver.receive()
        .groupBy(message -> message.receiverOffset().topicPartition())
        .flatMap(partitions -> partitions.concatMap(this::process));
```

**Unordered message processing**

In case sequence is not imporant and messages could be processed in any order we could increase throughput by processing multiple messages in parallel.

```
kafkaReceiver.receive()
        .flatMap(message -> process(message), concurrency);
```

Unordered message processing will support much higher throughput on a small number of partitions. For ordered message processing you would need to increase number of partitions to increase throughput.